# how to prove that$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{ n^4\over n!}=15e$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to prove that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{ n^4\over n!}=15e$$

I think this is a problem of exponential series.

Comment: $n^4 = n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3) + 6n(n-1)(n-2) + 7n(n-1) + n$

Comment: And now we must ask: can our over-eager answers wait until Debo has a chance to consider Daniel's hint.

Comment: Thank you  Daniel Fischer :-)

Answer (score 11):

Hint:

Let 
$$f(x)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$
If you differentiate it you get 
$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\cdot \frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}$$

Now $$x\cdot f'(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty  n\cdot \frac{x^n}{n!}$$
If you do this several times and look at $x=1$ at the value you get your sum.
(as $f(x)=\exp(x)$ you know the value of the left hand side)

Comment: How do I know the values of f'(x) ,f"(x) ?

Comment: @DebojyotiMukh the function is the exponentialfunction and we know that $f'(x)=f(x)$. And $\exp(1)=e$